# Scrolling SwipeRefreshLayout with RecyclerView Refresh anywhere in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have problem with my layout, I created SwipeRefreshLayout with RecyclerView inside.
in android 4.2.2+ all is working good, but in andorid 2.3.4 I cant to scroll up because in any place in the RecyclerView it will refresh, and I must to scroll down and then scroll up.

This is my code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/forum_swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LVP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I found this issue:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78191 but no a solution.
Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 11):

override RecyclerView's method `OnScrollStateChanged`

```
 mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
               try {
                   int firstPos = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                   if (firstPos > 0) {
                       mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                   } else {
                       mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                       if(mRecyclerView.getScrollState() == 1)
                           if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
                            mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                   }

               }catch(Exception e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "Scroll Error : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
               }
            }
```

Check if Swipe Refresh is Refreshing and try to Scroll up then you got error, so when swipe refresh is going on and i try do this `mRecyclerView.stopScroll();`

Comment: Only this method worked from me since I have emptyView and RecyclerView inside SwipeRefreshLayout. (Subclassing SwipeRefreshLayout and overriding `canChildScrollUp()` works though it messes up displaying my emptyView when there are no items. I don't however understand why the try/catch is necessary?

Comment: For me it work when i invert the condition.as i need to enable swipe refresh layout only when recyclerview position is at top.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the scroll up issue using the following code :

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        LinearLayoutManager manager = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
        boolean enabled =manager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0;
        pullToRefreshLayout.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
};
```

Then you need to use `setOnScrollListener` or `addOnScrollListener` depending if you have one or more listeners.

Comment: Works for small items, but will lead to issues if your first item cannot fit the screen bounds.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue and will be fixed in a future release.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78191

Meanwhile, if you need urgent fix, override `canChildScrollUp` in `SwipeRefreshLayout.java` and call `recyclerView.canScrollVertically(mTarget, -1)`. Because `canScrollVertically` was added after gingerbread, you'll also need to copy that method and implement in recyclerview.

Alternatively, if you are using LinearLayoutManager, you can call `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition`.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Did not fixed yet in supported library (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3`)

Comment: @yigit I'm still experiencing this issue with a RecyclerView within a SwipeRefreshLayout within a FrameLayout within a ViewPager. Using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1 should it be resolved?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable/enable the refresh layout based on recyclerview's scroll ability

```
    public class RecyclerSwipeRefreshHelper extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener{

    private static final int DIRECTION_UP = -1;


    private final SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

    public RecyclerSwipeRefreshHelper(
            SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout) {
        this.refreshLayout = refreshLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
       refreshLayout.setEnabled((recyclerView.canScrollVertically(DIRECTION_UP)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method canChildScrollUp() in SwipeRefreshLayout like this:

```
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
    if (mTarget instanceof RecyclerView) {
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mTarget;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            int position = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            return position != 0;
        } else if (layoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            int[] positions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) layoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(null);
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
                if (positions[i] == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
        if (mTarget instanceof AbsListView) {
            final AbsListView absListView = (AbsListView) mTarget;
            return absListView.getChildCount() > 0
                    && (absListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0 || absListView.getChildAt(0)
                            .getTop() < absListView.getPaddingTop());
        } else {
            return mTarget.getScrollY() > 0;
        }
    } else {
        return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(mTarget, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is a LinearLayoutManager, your solution may not work if setReverseLayout is set tot true. Instead, it should use canScrollVertically

Answer (score 0):

Based on @wrecker answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318447/7508302).

In Kotlin we can use extension method. So:

```
class RecyclerViewSwipeToRefresh(private val refreshLayout: SwipeToRefreshLayout) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    companion object {
        private const val DIRECTION_UP = -1
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        refreshLayout.isEnabled = !(recyclerView?.canScrollVertically(DIRECTION_UP) ?: return)
    }
}
```

And let's add extension method to RecyclerView to easly apply this fix to RV.

```
fun RecyclerView.fixSwipeToRefresh(refreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout): RecyclerViewSwipeToRefresh {
    return RecyclerViewSwipeToRefresh(refreshLayout).also {
        this.addOnScrollListener(it)
    }
}
```

Now, we can fix recyclerView using:

```
recycler_view.apply {
     ...
     fixSwipeToRefresh(swipe_container)
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me, please ensure that it is placed below the binding.refreshDiscoverList.setOnRefreshListener{} method.

```
 binding.swipeToRefreshLayout.setOnChildScrollUpCallback(object : SwipeRefreshLayout.OnChildScrollUpCallback {
        override fun canChildScrollUp(parent: SwipeRefreshLayout, child: View?): Boolean {
            if (binding.rvDiscover != null) {
                return binding.recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)
            }
            return false
        }
    })
```